# Ruby Rails - Make Table With created_at Column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

Ruby on rails has the t.timestamps method which creates two columns, created_at and updated_at.  How can I make just the created_at column?

This works

```
class CreateLinesSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lines_sources do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Both of these I want to work but fail

```
class CreateLinesSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lines_sources do |t|
      t.created_at null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateLinesSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lines_sources do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      remove_column updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try adding the timestamps in one migration, then removing `updated_at` in a later migration?

Comment: I would just create the `updated_at` too.  Even if you aren't using it worst case is it alerts you to an update that wasn't supposed to happen.  Why bother removing it when `ActiveRecord` kind of expects it?  Space savings are negligible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both attempts are okay but contains syntax error.

The problem on the first attempt is that the t. is on datatype not column name.

```
class CreateLinesSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lines_sources do |t|
      t.datetime :created_at, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The problem on the second attempt is that `remove_column` does not work inside `create_table` block. You can move it outside the block and provide correct syntax to remove the column.

```
class CreateLinesSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lines_sources do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    remove_column :line_sources, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: these days the column is `precision: 6, null: false`

Answer (score 26):

```
t.datetime :created_at, null: false
```

Just like any other column.  Rails will still take care of magic updating because of column name.

Comment: This answer is much better IMO. Because creating the `updated_at` column and removing it shortly after is kind of weird. Also +1 for adding a Rails behaviour for timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def change
  create_table :lines_sources do |t|
    t.datetime :created_at, null: false
  end
end
```